# Removing non-diagonal entries from a PSD matrix keeps the PSD property?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, sparse-matrices

I was thinking about positive semidefinite (PSD) sparse matrices and I began to wonder whether the following is true:

> Let $A$ be a PSD matrix and let $\bar{A}$ be obtained from $A$ by replacing some of its non-diagonal entries by zero, while keeping symmetry. Is $\bar{A}$ PSD as well?

Thanks!

Comment: on $2\times 2$ matrices, it is true

Comment: If the matrix is block diagonal then this will work. More generally if $\{P_i\}_i$ are a set of orthogonal projections then $\sum_i P_i A P_i$ should also be PSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is SPD, but
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has negative determinant, so it is not SPD.